While navigating my app using deep links, it opens my app. when I click the phone's back button repeatedly inside the app, it causes the app to crash
I am using a deep link to open my app, and it opens correctly. However, when I click the mobile back button repeatedly from within the app, it opens a blank screen. How can I resolve this problem?
When clicking the back button, I need to close my app and return to where the deep link was clicked.

What do you mean by it opens a blank screen? Is that still inside your app?

It opens a blank screen and stays inside my app, but this problem occurs only when using a deep link to open my app.

An no debug messages in the debug pane?

yes, there is no debug messages

use PopScope widget and navigate the user to the page you want when he pressed back button using onPopInvoked parameter , for example :
onPopInvoked: (bool didPop) {
                  //here you can add your navigation function 
              },

for more information about PopScope go to this link.

I have already used WillPopScope widget, and  its work fine when I open my app directly, but it shows a blank screen when I open my app using a deep link.
